# exiftool DPI disagrees with image properties on Windows 10 and the file linux command

Tags: image-editing, exif, exiftool

I'm trying to use the exiftool to set the DPI on a set of images to 300

I'm using the following command:

`./exiftool -jfif:Xresolution=300 -jfif:Yresolution=300 filename.jpg`

I've also tried:

`./exiftool -Xresolution=300 -Yresolution=300 filename.jpg`

When I query the dpi using exiftool I get the correct value:

Instead, when I query the file properties on Windows (right click, properties) or using the `file` linux command I get different values:

`JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 300x300, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, big-endian, direntries=4, xresolution=62, yresolution=70, resolutionunit=1], baseline, precision 8, 1440x1152, frames 3`

Windows shows DPI as 96x96

Are there any additional attributes needed to set?

Comment: You could just ignore it altogether, as DPI means absolutely nothing until you print the picture, or set it in a page-layout app. btw `density 300x300` **is** 300 dpi.

Comment: Try running `exiftool -G1 -a -s -*Resolution` to see all the resolution tags that are in the file and what groups they are a part of.  That said, when I run your first command on a file that doesn't have any resolution to start with, Windows shows the resolution as 300.